# Speed of linear dynamical system trajectory

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

[warning: biologist asking math question]

In a linear dynamical system, what feature of the matrix controls the speed of the trajectory in state space?

Say I have a matrix **M** describing how the system evolves per discrete time unit *t*: $$ \mathbf{x}_{t+1} = \mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{x}_t $$

The state of the system *n* time steps later is given by: $$ \mathbf{x}_{t+n} = \mathbf{M}^{n} \cdot \mathbf{x}_t $$

How should I modify **M** so as to reach state $\mathbf{x}_{t+n}$ in arbitrary fewer (or more) time steps?
In other words, what is matrix **P** so that $\mathbf{P}^{k \cdot n} = \mathbf{M}^{n}$ for arbitrary $k$ ? Is it a trivial question?

thanks,

Comment: you have to diagonalize $M$ or if it's not possible to put it in its [jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to compute a $k$th root of $M$.

If this is so, it really depends on what entries you allow. But at least you can do everything easily in the following (much simpler) situation: $M$ is diagonalizable and all eigenvalues of $M$ are positive real numbers.

Then you have $S^{-1}MS=D$ for some change of basis matrix $S$ and some diagonal matrix $D$ having the eigenvalues of $M$ on its main diagonal. Simply define $D'$ to be the diagonal matrix having entries on its main diagonal equal to the $k$th roots of the entries on the main diagonal of $D$ (this choice is not unique). Then the matrix $P=SD'S^{-1}$ satisfies $P^k=M$.